# How to transform these shapes from xml to java code?

Tags: android, android-xml, shapes, android-shape, shapedrawable

I'm searching on google how to transform these shapes to java code but I can't find the way, also I checked the documentation and nothing...

These are the shapes:

shape1.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:shape="oval" >    
    <gradient
        android:endColor="#ffff6600"
        android:gradientRadius="150"
        android:startColor="#ffffcc00"
        android:type="radial"
        android:useLevel="false" />    
    <size
        android:height="100dp"
        android:width="100dp" />    
</shape>
```

shape2.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:shape="rectangle" >    
    <solid android:color="#339933"/>    
</shape>
```

Which is the correct java code transformation for these simple shapes?

Comment: learn about Drawables. "ShapeDrawable"